# Deleting and freeing QGraphicsItem class derived objects

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have derived from the `QGraphicsItem` class and drawing some custom shapes. These multiple shapes are then added to a `QGraphicsScene`.

```
class StairCurve : public QObject, public CurveShape, public QGraphicsItem

class BezierCurve: public QObject, public CurveShape, public QGraphicsItem
```

`CurveShape` is a class which has some common properties related to these curves like ID etc. It doesn't derive from anything else. It has some `pure virtual` functions though.

For deleting all the beziers from scene, I am doing something like this :

```
        QList<QGraphicsItem*> all = selectedItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++)
        {
            QGraphicsItem * item = all[i];

            if( NULL != item && (BezierCurve::Type == item->type()) )
            {
                removeItem(item);
                delete item;
                item  = NULL;
            }
       }
```

`QGraphicsItem * item = all[i];` will return a pointer to the base class part of my object. So calling remove on it looks good to me. This object will not be a part of scene any more.

My concern is that calling `delete` on `item` will call the destructor on the base class, right ? I don't think it will remove the complete object from memory. Will doing something like this make more sense :

```
delete dynamic_cast<BezierCurve*>(item);
```

More formally,

```
Class A : public B, public C
Class B : public D

A *a;
```

To delete the object `a`, the correct way is using `delete` operator on `a`, rather than on any of the base class objects in the hierarchy, correct ?

And does the use of `virtual destructors` relate to all this in any ways?

Comment: Note that your deletion code can be very dangerous, as if you have both a parent and a child selected, and you delete the parent, the child will be delete too (so your delete on it would constitute a double deletion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QGraphicsItem` has a [virtual destructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#dtor.QGraphicsItem). Thus if you call `delete item;`, where `item` is a pointer of type `QGraphicsItem`, the destructors of all derived classes will be called first. To test this, just implement the destructor of the `StairCurve` class and see whether it is called.